# General Topology-book recommendations

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, book-recommendation

Can you suggest some introduction books on the topics below in topology, that have classic problems and exercises?

Topics:

**Locally compact spaces. Locally connected spaces. Continua of Peano. Definitions of topological dimension. The concept of the topology curve. Convex subsets and cells.Maps between simplices. Lemma of Sperner and Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem. Simplicial complexes and polyhedra. Euler’s characteristic of polyhedron.**

Comment: Armstrong's Basic Topology and then Hatcher's Algebraic Topology.

Comment: @Oolongmilktea thanks a lot, I will check them.

Comment: the topics that you quoted are not of general topology, rather than algebraic topology

Comment: @Masacroso I wouldn't know that, my course is called general topology II, should I change the title ?